# How to run xlswrite with formula in loop function

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop, dynamic, export

I have a large cell (2500x3) array which I want to export as an `.xls` file, but I want to include a formula (`'=SUM(B1:C1)'`) which can be used in Excel.

The code below is working fine but I want the `B1` and `C1` to increase by `1` in each iteration (`'=SUM(B1:C1)', '=SUM(B2:C2)', '=SUM(B3:C3)'` etc). How can I do this? My present loop code is:

```
for II = 1:length(out)
  out{II,4}='=SUM(B1:C1)';
end

xlswrite('Book1.xls',out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
for II = 1:3
  out{II} = sprintf('=SUM(B%u:C%u)', II, II);
end
```

Which gives us:

```
out =

  1×3 cell array

    {'=SUM(B1:C1)'}    {'=SUM(B2:C2)'}    {'=SUM(B3:C3)'}
```